# Use Wordpress engine for user registration and management

Tags: user-access, user-registration, authentication

I am building a web app and would like to use the Wordpress Engine only for Authentication and User Management. Is there any good tutorials out there on how I can connect only the back end of wordpress to my simple app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be good starting point for you:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website
http://codex.wordpress.org/Developer_Documentation (see function reference for admin-related functions list)